# I am trying to figure out what I know to be an easy proof but I am having troubles.

Tags: limits

whats the value of limit of F(x) where x tends to 0 . $$f(x) =  (x^2)\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$$?
 Can i also do it using squeeze theorem here? if yes how ? if not why?

Comment: Hint: for any $x\ne0$, $-x^2<x^2\sin(1/x^2)<x^2$.

Comment: Since $|\sin(y)| \leq 1$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "I am having troubles": what kind of troubles ?

Comment: Note that you can boost your reputation on the website by accepting answers. To do this just click the check mark underneath the downvote arrow on the answer you would like to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-1 \leq \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})\leq 1 $

$\Rightarrow -x^2 \leq x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})\leq x^2$

and then use the squeeze theorem to conclude that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is let $u=\frac{1}{x^2}$ and substitute this back into the expression to obtain $\frac{\sin (u)}{u}$. Now as $x \to 0$, $u$ tends towards infinity. Since $-1< \sin (u)<1$, we can apply the squeeze theorem to obtain:

$\frac{-1}{u} <\frac{\sin (u)}{u} <\frac{1}{u}$. Now as $u\to \infty$ we get that $\pm \frac{1}{u} \to 0$ and so our expression is sandwiched in between two zeroes. This tells us that our limit is also zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1** - squeezing using limsup and liminf.
$$\begin{align}
& \forall x \ne 0, -x^2 \le F(x) \le x^2 \\
\implies & 0 = \liminf_{x\to 0}(-x^2) \le \liminf_{x\to 0} F(x) \le \limsup_{x\to 0} F(x) \le \limsup_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0\\
\implies & \liminf_{x\to 0} F(x) = \limsup_{x\to 0} F(x) = 0\\
\iff & \lim_{x\to 0} F(x) = 0
\end{align}
$$
**Method 2** - by $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ such that for all $x$ with $0 < |x| < \delta$, we have 
$$|F(x) - 0 | = \left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right| \le x^2 < \delta^2 = \epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrary small, by definition of limit,
$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} F(x) = 0$.